# read file containing Hex values and process it

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, numeric-data

[image: trace of memory referances made by a program]
i want to read the values in the third column and find the difference from the other value in the same column.
i tried this

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
 NR==1 {prev=$3;next; }
dif=prev - $3;
{printf "%x",dif}
{print $3, dif > "diff"}
```

But since the values are hexadecimal im getting a zero as the difference.

Comment: post few (3-5) lines as text, don't post an image as ppl cannot copy paste for testing solutions...

Comment: @Sundeep ok would take care in future

Comment: you can click https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/407080/edit to do it in this question itself.. also add expected output for clarity

Comment: No files contain "hex values". Hex is just a representation, there is nothing specially "hex" in any value. Better call it a non-text or possibly non-ASCII file. `file` calls such files "data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that, on input, awk does not automatically interpret hex numbers.  You have to ask it to do that explicitly using the `strtonum` function.  Thus, when you need the number in your code, replace `$3` with `strtonum($3)`.

#### Example

Let's take this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
0x7f7488c4e6d7: R 0x7f7488b169ce
0x7f7488c4e6e9: R 0x7f7488b169cc
0x7f7488c4e6f8: R 0x7f7488b169d0
```

Let's use this as the script:

```
$ cat a.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR==1 {
    prev=strtonum($3)
    next
}
{
    dif=prev - strtonum($3)
    printf "%x\n",dif
    print $3, dif > "diff"
}
```

The screen output looks like:

```
$ ./a.awk file
2
fffffffffffffffe
```

The output file is:

```
$ cat diff
0x7f7488b169cc 2
0x7f7488b169d0 -2
```